# Track Generalist badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

The new badge tracker is pretty cool, but I wonder why the [Generalist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist) cannot be tracked.

It's one of the hardest badges to get, and it's probably the most interesting in my opinion (it encourages people to find interest or learn new languages/technologies). Unfortunately, tracking it by hand is pretty hard, and I would love to have it in my tracker.

Comment: Yes please! However, note this is not specific to SO. Perhaps this suggestion should be raised on MSE too/instead?

Comment: The general point that some badges can't be tracked was raised on MSE. The response was that some are excluded because the cost of calculation is too high.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254073/184077

Answer (score 6):

Here is a SEDE query: [Generalist Badge Progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76727/generalist-progression-updated).

This is from the much more extensive list of SEDE queries for badge progress on MSE: [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/143653#143653).

Answer (score 2):

Until the cost of calculating and tracking Generalist can come down a bit, [StinkingBadges](https://stackapps.com/q/2982/14585) has been capable of tracking this very thing for *years*.

It'd be nice if this were baked in to the system, as we've already got support for a decent number of badges, but until that time comes, the app will suffice.