# Why was I awarded the Generalist badge? Is it a bug?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

[I was awarded the Generalist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist?userid=918959) - which I was aiming for. But then I checked my score with [Stinking Badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/) and it said that I've got high enough score only in 16 tags. Then I tried the SEDE query from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291475/918959) - and the same result.

There are 17 pages of Generalist badges - 4 pages or ~25 % of the generalists to date were awarded last (UTC) night. Is this a bug, or were the criteria changed? (And am I stupid for reporting this here in case my badge is reverted? ;)

Comment: Easy hand-verifiable case: http://stackoverflow.com/users/191459/dave. A quick scan shows 15 qualifying tags (quite a feat with only 129 answers, but not generalist material). Only if you ignore the minimum tag score requirement would they go past the 20 tag minimum.

Comment: @MartijnPieters perhaps the requirement now is "at least 15 total score over all the posts in these tags" :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Doesn't work for the user that Martijn has found. Although I only checked answer scores.

Comment: @ArtjomB: yes it does. They easily have more than 15 upvotes *total* for the 20 or more tags from the top 40.

Comment: Can't even be the question score, I have only 8 questions, none of which contain any of the remaining top-40 tags that aren't covered by those 16 tags.

Comment: The criteria, de facto changed to needing only 15 tags.  This appears only to have happened on SO, not any other sites that I checked.  This is probably a glitch. Blame *Documentation*? ;)

Comment: If I randomly got the Generalist badge, I wouldn't report it here. Jokes aside, I believe this is a glitch.

Comment: Same here. I got it while [Stinking badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge) says I _just_ have 17 out of the top 20 tags with a >=15 score.

Comment: @BrockAdams Are you sure? [StinkingBadges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge) and [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/76727/generalist-progression-updated) tell me I'm on 18/20 but I [don't have the badge yet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist?userid=1663001).

Comment: @DavidG, with your counter-example, I'm now not sure.  I semi randomly checked 5 people (plus Martijn Pieters' example), then spot-checked 4 other sites.  Maybe the glitch has other/additional criteria.

Comment: @BrockAdams It's possible that you're still correct and since it changed it requires me to gain *another* relevant tag score of 15, so my 19th might grant it. However, I don't think that's how the badge calculations work.

Comment: @DavidG, Yeah, seems unlikely.  Alas we only know 3 things for certain(ish):  (1) SO awarded a *bunch* of badges to those not worthy ;) , (2) Other sites don't seem to be affected, (3) Generalist really should be a gold badge. I mean, come on!

Comment: @BrockAdams Oh completely agree! There's definitely something wrong though. a little over 1000 of those badges awarded ever and about 250 in the last 20 hours? Hmmm. Also [this made me laugh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0atgr.png), good job Jeff!

Comment: Oh, and we are apparently awarding badges to [suspended users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2767755/arup-rakshit) too!

Comment: No news after 10 days. Do we have a rule like "Once given for ten days, the buggy badge remains yours forever"?

Comment: @fedorqui, well I'd rather have a special gold badge "Extreme honesty" for having a badge reversed due to a bug reported on SO :P

Comment: I got this badge even though I do not fulfill the "top 40" tags requirement. However, if I move up to "top 50" it does work to me. [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/667337/generalist-top-50) -- however, it does not work with yours, Antti.

Comment: I feel like this question has been a little bit ignored here. Over 6 weeks and nothing seems to have happened? (cc @fedorqui and you thought 10 days was a long time! :)

Comment: This bug appears to still be happening - I just got a Generalist badge, even though I only have enough score in 15 of the top 40 tags. I do have 20 score in 15 of the top 40 tags, but I do not have 15 score in 20 of the top 40 tags. Maybe something got switched around?

Comment: Looks like 25 pages worth of people just got the badge.

Answer (score 9):

So I've done a bit of digging in here and yeah, a glitch happened, but there's no real way for us to know what it was.

[image: Generalist Badges Granted Over Time]

We can see that on that fateful day in April 2017 a bunch of Generalists were minted. (fun fact: I am an honored recipient from this day). There are a few other days where it happened at a much smaller scale.

The generalist badge is granted by checking a denormalized count of tags, and those counts aren't logged anywhere. I tried to rebuild history from history entries we do have (a couple times) but my efforts led me to believe the computation is akin to a harder rep history calculation (because we need it by tag) + rebuilding post/tag liveness throughout history. It's real hard.

Sorry for failing :(