# Incorrectly awarded Generalist badges (again)

Tags: bug, status-review, badges

I just got a Generalist badge that I do not qualify for. Looking at the [list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15) of people who have the badge, it looks like over half the people with the badge just got it today. The badges seem to have been awarded in two clusters, one about 20 minutes ago (3 AM UTC) and one about 2 hours and 20 minutes ago (1 AM UTC).

This is very similar to [another incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346660/why-was-i-awarded-the-generalist-badge-is-it-a-bug) with Generalist badges back in 2017.

Comment: Yeah.~26 pages of generalist badges awarded today when the entire previous lifetime of the badge only awarded ~19 pages of badges since 2010 definitely seems something went wrong somewhere.